# Steepest Descent Algorithm in Octave

Tags: octave, mathematical-optimization

I'm having trouble implementing this algorithm in octave even though the psuedocode for this algorithm looks really simple. The book covering this algorithm is only 1 page long, so there are not a lot of information regarding this algorithm, so I'm just going to post the psedocode:

```
Compute r = b - Ax and  p = A r
Until convergence, Do:
     a <- (r,r) / (p,r)
     x <- x + a r
     r <- r - r p
     compute p := A r
End do
```

Here is my attempt at implementing this in Octave. I use an example in the book to test the program:

```
A = [5,2,-1;3,7,3;1,-4,6];
b = [2;-1;1];
x0 = [0;0;0];
Tol = 0.00001;

x=x0;

r = b-A*x;
p = A*r;
while true,
    a = (r')*(r)/((p)*(r'));
    disp(a);
    x = x + a * r;
    r = r - a * p;
    p = A*r;
    if norm(r) < Tol,
        break
    end
end
```

When I run this, i get an error saying that the first matrix im dividing with is 1x1 and the second matrix is 3v3, so I'm not able to do that and I understand that. I thought about using the ./ operator instead, but to my understanding this does not yield the result that I'm looking for and this example should be eligble to division. Did i screw up my implementation or is my understanding of this algorithm wrong? Not sure whether to post this here or math.stackexchange, but I tried here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought is the error message: You have `(r') * (r) / ((p) * (r'))`; should the denominator be `(p) * (r')` or `(p') * (r)` (notice where the `'` are)?

Comment: The denominator should be (p) * (r'), because r is transposed and I added the extra parenthesis to mark the expression as the denominator. I tried to move the ' outside the parenthesis giving me ((p)*(r)') which didn't give me an error message for some reason. I'm very confused now.

Comment: I ask because this is what seems to be causing the error, when I tried your example it turns out that p*(r') is a singular matrix in the first place, so division by it doesn't make sense.  The notation in the pseudocode (p,r) looks like the inner product, which should always evaluate to a number; if this is true the denominator should be ((p') * r).  When I run your example with this change, r does shrink below the tolerance level after a dozen or so iterations.